# Remove Spaces, Maintaining Capitalization

Tags: code-golf, string

Your input will be an English sentence, phrase, or word. It will only contain `a-zA-Z' -,.!?`. Your task is to take the input, remove spaces, and then redistribute capitalization such that letters at indexes that were capitalized before (and only letters at indexes that were capitalized before) are capitalized.

For example, if the input is `A Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Dog`, the (0-based) indexes of the capital letters are `0, 2, 8, 14, 18, 25, 30, 34, 39`. Next, remove spaces from the input: `AQuickBrownFoxJumpedOverTheLazyDog`. Next, lowercase all letters, but uppercase those at `0, 2, 8, 14, 18, 25, 30, 34, 39`: `AqUickbrOwnfoxJumpEdovertHelazYdog`, which is your output.

## Input

Your input will be an English sentence, phrase, or word. It can only contain lowercase letters, uppercase letters, hyphens, apostrophes, commas, periods, question marks, exclamation marks, and spaces.

## Output

The input with spaces removed, lowercase-d, with letters at the index of capital letters in the input uppercase-d.

NOTE: Your program cannot crash (error such execution terminates) with an IndexOutOfRange or similar error.

## Test Cases

```
Hi! Test!
Hi!tEst!

A Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Dog
AqUickbrOwnfoxJumpEdovertHelazYdog

testing TESTing TeStING testing testing TESTING
testingtESTIngteStInGTEstingtestingtestiNG

TESTING... ... ... success! EUREKA???!!! maybe, don't, NOOOOO
TESTING.........success!eureKA???!!!maybe,don't,nooooo

Enter        PASSWORD ---------
Enterpassword---------

A a B b C c D d E e F f G g H h I i J j K k L l M m N n O o P p Q q R r S s T t U u V v W w X x Z z
AabbCcddEeffGghhIijjKkllMmnnOoppQqrrSsttUuvvWwxxZz

  TEST
teST
```

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/13115#13115)

Comment: 'For example, if the input is "A Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Dog", the (0-based) indexes of the capital letters are `0, 2, 8, 14, 18, 23, 27, 32`' They are `0, 2, 8, 14, 18, 25, 30, 34, 39`

Comment: @LukeSawczak thank you, my bad

Comment: Traling spaces not allowed, I assume?

Comment: @LuisMendo your assumption is correct. This is code-golf, right? :P

Comment: Can we assume the first character won't be a space?

Comment: @xnor No, I'll add a test case. Sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
nŒlTɓḲFŒlŒuṛ¦
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/v6KSckJOTH@7Y5AZkHZ1U@nDn7EPL/v//76gQWJqZnK3gVJRfnqfgll@h4FWaW5CaouBfllqkEJKRquCTWFWp4JKfDgA)

#### How it works

```
nŒlTɓḲFŒlŒuṛ¦  Main link. Argument: s (string)

 Œl            Convert s to lowercase.
n              Perform character-wise "not equal" comparison.
   T           Get the indices of all truthy elements, i.e., the indices of all
               uppercase letters in s. Let's call the resulting array J.
    ɓ          Begin a dyadic chain with left argument s and right argument J.
     ḲF        Split s at spaces and flatten, removing the spaces.
       Œl      Convert s to lowercase.
            ¦  Sparse application:
         Œu        Convert s to uppercase.
           ṛ       Take the resulting items of the uppercased string at all indices
                   in J, the items of the lowercased string at all others.
```

Answer (score 14):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>82</s> <s>79</s> <s>74</s> <s>72</s> <s>69</s> <s>67</s> 66 bytes

```c
f(c){for(char*s=c,*p=c;c=*s++;c&&putchar(c^(*p++|~c/2)&32))c&=95;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBNT8JgEITP8iuecqgtBUwwHkxDCEgVAUFoEePBpLwUqEhb@wGC4l/HYiDxwCSb3cxkZjcrClMhdruJItSviR8qYmaHuags8rmgLHRRzkWapgtZDpJ4LyniVckFmvb9Iy5KqnxZUlUhl6@v9O1uYbueoma@MmcTJdtwJSwniqWsqmfOUnOkZP/GVKvSS1wxpxb6K49b/5NmsgicMd2lE2LNHNr2Zk3dn54wx2mo602xDNP6644Z33fuOPL/9ZQ/kXBQisUix4oSIZwokjAGfaNVrVQqkiSxsNcjJ8/Y987jPJ3uHifyDC9Ozz7gsWqaw26/TuGIkw@wqTHiBkGdMQYOt0y4Y0qDGfe4NHmjxZw27zywoINHF59HAnp80CfEJMIiZkDCE0uGrHjmkxc2@1Xb3S8)

Comment: this will segfault if the `char*` doesn't fit in an `int`, which can be fixed for [+2 bytes](https://tio.run/##bZHdTsJAFISv5Sm@9gJbUEw0XpiGEJT6g0qVVjEaTepSoCJt7W5VRH11LAiJMUyy2ZOZPXNOZsVmX4jpVFg9Qwz8tCTNSS9Of@ukKi1RLcly2RLFYpKpGWuIB6OUlMuf32Jr2yzubJumKFb3dq2v6cgPI8MsTAprPUM/DjW8QCpNN63CWt4sDX1e5lqdyywUQ/bT@C3iMH6nmY2SoIvzGqR4g4Az/2NMI@6vaFa5aRj18WzXm9@Bq05aRyz5v3rOr3BYKJVKheWRmRCBlBr2Vds@rddqNU3TGPnjx2CDbhytqw1azgwr/OxI5WsvcFF33Y7TbrC5xMoAfPZ55ABBgy42AYf0OKLPMQNOCGnyxClDznjmnBEtIhxiLki45IU2KS4SD8UVGde80uGNG9655eP/1NnfIe/uq7qr0lk@TjRP2lW@GOrztWT@7mv6Aw)

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 114 bytes

```python
x=input()
X=x.replace(' ','')
print''.join([X[i].upper()if x[i].isupper()else X[i].lower()for i in range(len(X))])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcqxCsIwEIDhvU9xdEkOJIN7JwdfIVA6FL3oSbg70hTj00cqjv/Hb5/6VDn33iYW26vHIU4tFLK83sg7cCfncLDCUp0LL2Xxc5x5CbsZFY@coB3J2x8obwS/I@v7gKQFGFigrPIgn0l8RFyw9/Gid4Kr5jR@AQ)

## Equivalently:

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 114 bytes

```python
lambda x:''.join([[str.lower,str.upper][x[i].isupper()](x.replace(' ','')[i])for i in range(len(x)-x.count(' '))])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYoxDsIwDEWvks22VDIwIjExcIiQIbQOBIU4clsRTh9atvfe//W7PKUcezzfeg7v@xRMOwHYl6SCzs2L2iwf1mGntVZW75pL3qb5b0gem1WuOYyMYGAAoG2nKGqSScVoKA/GzAUbHZodZS3LfiTy1KumzSLCRSY2V8lx6/0H)

Comment: `''.join([(X[i].lower,X[i].upper)[x[i].isupper()]()for i in range(len(X))])` for -5 bytes.

Comment: 96 bytes: `x=input();print''.join([(c+c).title()[1-x[i].isupper()]for i,c in enumerate(x.replace(' ',''))])`

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>78</s> <s>75</s> 72 bytes

```python
s=input()
for c in s:s=s[c>' '!=print(end=(c+c).title()[s<'@'or'['<s]):]
```

*Thanks to @xnor for golfing off 6 bytes!*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZBLT8JAFIX3/RVfV9MqsjFxQaiIUt6C0ipG4gLLABWY1s4UwT@P9UHil9yc5NxHTm66N8tEnR/kTkaOEOKgvViluXFca55kRMQKXdGenkSXAmF7aRYr40g185zoNHLLJjZr6bgTXRVXIsnERFT1i1t5OfwOusVNTrhwD@3YJpTa2Fad@zyOVlxnyYeimezo5ptUzhhuZUa4lPSnn3saycIyxUKsFoR@EP6oDExn0OLo/@8XvvWn5XKZY@k8iqTWNv7DyO/Va7WabdtspvtXWWKWKGFKDIbfWL4yRYA/7upBMB6OGpwdKYJPueaVm@IvDWb4SJrMabGgzZIOMV3e6LGiz5pbNgxQDEm4I@Wed0ZkBGhCDA/kPLJlzAdP7Hjm8ws)

Comment: Can you just compare `s` instead of `s[0]`?

Comment: Yes, of course. Thanks!

Comment: `(c*2).title()` can get you both cases, though switched.

Comment: Another 3 bytes. Thanks again!

Comment: Tricky! Took me a while to figure out that `c>' '!=f()` is equivalent to `(c>' ') and (' '!=f())`.

Comment: Breaks, if the string contains an `@`. Should be `[s<'A'or'['<s]`

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>15</s> 14 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [Emigna](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47066/emigna)

```
ðKuvy¹Nè.lil}?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFJcgEBAADAr/QLFAdnZYtdRATlooxdhtiDKv9xdHXlYaM7nhwEiXEUve6V8Hh@PuqvWyzszw/XVBSlDWQEsoZyRvLGPkwUTBXNlMyVLVT8qgrVLNWtfPrTsPZlo2nr207L3o@DtqOOf10nPZc3)

```
ðK             # Remove spaces
  u            # Convert to uppercase
   vy          # For each character...
     ¹Nè       #   Get the character at the same index from the original input
        .lil}  #   If it was a lowercase letter change this one to lowercase
             ? # Print without a newline
```

Comment: You save a byte if you uppercase the space-removed string and lowercase it in the condition.

Answer (score 5):

### [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>98</s> <s>95</s> <s>89</s> <s>88</s> 81 bytes

*Thanks to @name, @nimi, @Zgarb, and @Laikoni for helping shave off 14 bytes total*

```
import Data.Char
\s->zipWith(\p->last$toLower:[toUpper|isUpper p])s$filter(>' ')s
```

Ungolfed:

```
import Data.Char
\sentence -> zipWith (\oldChar newChar ->
                        if isUpper oldChar
                        then toUpper newChar
                        else toLower newChar)
                     sentence
                     (filter (/= ' ') sentence)
```

Comment: On mobile, but looks like you can save some bytes with filter(/=' ')

Comment: Yep, certainly can. Missed the part of the spec noting that spaces were the only whitespace that needed removing.

Comment: `filter(>' ')` for one byte less

Comment: I think the body of the lambda can be shortened to `last(toLower:[toUpper|isUpper p])c`

Comment: Switching the arguments of `zipWith` should save one more byte: `f s=zipWith(\p->last$toLower:[toUpper|isUpper p])s$filter(>' ')s`.

Comment: I tried something cute, but it came out saving 0 bytes: `f=toLower;\s->zipWith(\p->last$f:[toUpper|f p<p])s$filter(>' ')s`

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, 100 bytes

```
s=input()
print"".join([c.lower(),c.upper()][s[i].isupper()]for i,c in enumerate(s.replace(" ","")))
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG, and very good first answer!

Answer (score 4):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 24 bytes

```
ÄVuÓó
ejlDò/¥2lõ
vuk~òGd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFJEsFAGIDRfU7x3UCVGyDEPASh7JAYkjYE3UlZWLmBM7hAlAv4D9beM9bKM9Dyko8TxcqVovR7l5V8HaOThxReaG2FJVVW1FjjElInosEGjy1NdrTY0yamQ0IXRY8DfY4MODHkzIgUnwtjrky4MUUTYJiRMSdnwf0P)

These kind of challenges are exactly what V was made for. :)

Explanation:

```
Ä           " Duplicate this line
 Vu         " Convert it to lowercase
   Óó       " Remove all spaces
e           " Move to the end of this line
 j          " Move down a line (to the original)
  l         " Move one char to the right
   D        " And delete the end of this line
    ò       " Recursively:
     /      "   Search for:
         õ  "     An uppercase character
      ¥2l   "     On line 2
            "     (This will break the loop when there are no uppercase characters left)
vu          "   Convert it to lowercase
  k         "   Move up a line
   ~        "   Convert this to uppercase also
    ò       " Endwhile
     G      " Move to the last line
      d     " And delete it
```

Comment: @DLosc Good questions! The newlines signal the end of a regex command, such as a substitute (remove) or search command. More detail is on this page: https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V/wiki/Regexes

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>94</s> <s>91</s> <s>85</s> <s>84</s> 81 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.replace(r=/./g,c=>1/c?"":c[`to${r<s[x]&s[x++]<{}?"Upp":"Low"}erCase`](),x=0)
```

- 6 bytes saved with assistance from ETHproductions & Arnauld.
- 3 bytes saved thanks to l4m2

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY9rT8JAEEW/@ytOG6MQsOg3YywNSn0iKC1iJCTWZcGqtHV3eajxt2M1YsSbzExyJnNn5jGaRlqoODNb093F0F1ot6odJbPnSMiCcitOZVQWbnWnIjzb3hO9O5Ouv6t93Zv3N/JUKvX33z88u5Nl9p7dSGf2h1SHkZZ3/UKxPHe3i4tMxYkpDAv2SWwRSm0su1hc@6U1riaxeOJApbOEo3TO2WScyQGtqVSED5JG9PZKPR2tjJncKE5GhH4QflcZmNPmMUv@t5/zldkf5jgOy9ATIaTWFn6n7Z/XPM@zLItx9HovywzSZNOUaba@tOLkJyY/8keXtSDottp1tpb692jEAfccIqgzwEdyxJBjRpzwwCkxZzxyzhMNnrlgTJOEFimXZFzxQhtFgCbE0GHCNVO6zLhhzi1vK/v4/j1Hi08)

Comment: Ninjad :P https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128951/65836

Comment: Could you do `'@'<s[i]&s[i]<'['?`?

Comment: @StepHen: Aw, man, didn't see that last night while I was working on this.

Comment: @ETHproductions: I was wondering if that might be shorter but I was too lazy to look up which characters I'd need to use :D Turns out it doea save a byte; thanks.

Comment: [Fail](https://tio.run/##DcSxCoMwEADQX5GjlAStOhbxzNC1aycJGI5YLFKPS7CC@O2pb3gft7pAMnG8rfc0YgrYhVI8z468EqzK6l0QdoQIGRiAhvohLpdd2tBv9nqW57bdDwMvZmjgufzg8PJwwQ9W6WLDWieW6RvVqCAzDrROfw) but your last version work and same length

Comment: `c==" "` => `c<"!"` or even `1/c`

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>117</strike> <strike>114</strike> 98 bytes

```
s=input()
i,*y=0,*s.replace(' ','').lower()
for c in y:print(end=[c,c.upper()]['@'<s[i]<'[']);i+=1
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##FcqxCsIwEADQ3a@47doaiuKmBlTEQQQR3EKHkp42WJMjbazx56O@@XEcWmcXKfXSWA5Dlk@MKKKciaIvPXFXa8oQUCDmZedG8r9xcx40GAtxyd7YISPbSKWFLgPzf1QKN7julanWqLDKV2Yq5ylt4RKMfsDOu9HCwb3hGJ5MDZxf5OHaEpzqT4S9u38B)

**Edit:** 3 bytes saved by UndoneStudios.

**Edit:** 14 bytes saved by Unrelated String.

This is pretty much my first code golf, so it's likely to be bad, minus help from comments below!

P.S. Yes, it's dumb that defining and incrementing `i` saves bytes over range(len(y)). Oh well.

---

## Python 3, 85 bytes

```
lambda s:''.join([c,c.upper()]['@'<b<'[']for b,c in zip(s,s.replace(' ','').lower()))
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##FctBC4IwFADgv/Jub4OxS5cIg4rwEEEE3czDnDNXuveYmumft/ruH099TWG15rhU2/vSmLYoDXQbRP0kH0RmldUDs4tC5hnuMCkSzDCvKEKhLPgAs2fRqU5Hx42xTiCgQpS6ofG/pFw4@tCLSuAeroO3LzhEGgOk9IHT0LIr4fJ2EW61g7OZJzjSA3/tCw)

This solution is entirely due to att; I'm keeping it separate because the strategy seems to me to have changed enough.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice first submission! However, complying to our site's I/O standards, your submission must either be a function of a string or take input; you cannot assume input is in a variable. Hope you enjoy your stay! :)

Comment: Thanks; edited a function in, but also saved 5 bytes in the body :D

Comment: @LukeSawczak save a ton of bytes by changing to one space for indentation, and maybe add a Try It Online! link if you want to

Comment: You can remove the space after `return`.

Comment: @LukeSawczak how's this? https://tio.run/##LY3JTsMwAAXv@Yq52RZRBOJWKQf2fS2bQBxKalOXYBvboYSfD6nEcaR580KfF95tD8NcG4xMalJgy77eLFubskxV1KGdNVoKRCmEqlq/0lEqVWB8pME6@nGDNaQX@1rZ1IWwNib9iHVT/eNa2ai3CqLOXXRCVEtvnexVEaJ1WRppXejyWFbDsMOMXd7YGw/2mXOA5hDDEe8cs@AEyylLzvjgnJYLPrnEcYXnmsANX9wSmZK4I3NPxwPfPLLiiR@e@f0D

Comment: @StephenS Thank you! Sorry, I deleted my comment after realizing I could both make a working TIO *and* save bytes by using `input`/`print`, but that's good to know.

Comment: [-3 bytes?](https://tio.run/##LcpBCsMgEEDRvaeY3Wgr0tJdwJOELIoYMiWMgxrKnN6mkOXjf9G@FX6N0SKxHN06Q17jw8@3FmqW/Z2yRUCP6MJevrlat5i1VEhADDoZoBXaTEugdoj8@6QnYwoXz@Men0YqcbeI4VOIrTo3xg8 "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @UndoneStudios Thanks!

Comment: [shaved it down a bit more](https://tio.run/##FcqxCsIwEADQ3a@47doaiuKmBlTEQQQR3EKHkp42WJMjbazx56O@@XEcWmcXKfXSWA5Dlk@MKKKciaIvPXFXa8oQUCDmZedG8r9xcx40GAtxyd7YISPbSKWFLgPzf1QKN7julanWqLDKV2Yq5ylt4RKMfsDOu9HCwb3hGJ5MDZxf5OHaEpzqT4S9u38B)

Comment: [85 bytes](https://tio.run/##FctBC4IwFADgv/Jub4OxS5cIg4rwEEEE3czDnDNXuveYmumft/ruH099TWG15rhU2/vSmLYoDXQbRP0kH0RmldUDs4tC5hnuMCkSzDCvKEKhLPgAs2fRqU5Hx42xTiCgQpS6ofG/pFw4@tCLSuAeroO3LzhEGgOk9IHT0LIr4fJ2EW61g7OZJzjSA3/tCw)

Comment: @att Cool. Added as a separate solution because it's a bit more of a leap than the others, but if you'd rather just make it an answer yourself, feel free to keep it and I'll purge it from mine.

Comment: the strategy is basically the same, only using `zip` instead of explicit indices

Comment: @att Right, but given the smallness (as I believe) of the solution space, it doesn't take that much to be a different way of doing it. I guess I'm also thinking of the overall drift from my first attempt and the likelihood that I would ever have eventually arrived at `zip`. But anyway, I'm happy to leave it in.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>77</s> 71 bytes

```
.+
$&¶$&
T`L `l_`.+$
+`((.)*)[A-Z].*(¶(?<-2>.)*)
$1$3 
.+¶

T`l `L_` .?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7ZTsJQFEXf71esJhULhZuor8YGpUwiU@sQjaEMV6hAq7TI8GF8AD9Wi4HElZzsZJ3sZC9U7Af95MyoeIk0hZ7Z7/SMcL0G3qznSVMXpmcYMpvLvhULr@8yZ@x3hnVduLw5OKFf6FcIae53Ii3N8Bo9D2klSdXXcFUUa6JIZ@kPp9wuwlVAOVxTX86/1IjWj1rgThSN/nZDKRyLOC34wRjXdty/VE5ca1Y4@f//1ItjSik5XbQcDlUUadiPXfu@aFmWpmnM@5uByjMKg/M4T7N1QNhBnA440i46znOrW6JwIh3e55YBdwwpMcJGUeaDCmOqTKjhU@eTe6Y0mPHAnCYBLULafNHhmy4LHCJcYh5Z8sQPz6x4Yc0r218) Link includes test suite. Explanation: The first stage duplicates the line while the second stage lowercases the duplicate and deletes its spaces. The third stage then loops through each uppercase letter from right to left and attempts to place a space before the corresponding character on the second line. The first line is deleted and the spaces are used to uppercase the relevant characters of the result. Edit: Saved 6 bytes thanks to @Kobi.

Comment: Small question: Are the `(.?)` and `$4` parts needed? It looks like having an optional group at the end does nothing.

Comment: @Kobi Nothing small about that question! It had originally been part of an attempt at using lookarounds to match the characters to be uppercased directly instead of having to translate them as a separate step.

Answer (score 3):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 32 bytes

```
/..- ~l+u~mSloy
\ia''-y.'Qa.+a@/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/19fT09XoS5Hu7QuNzgnv5IrJjNRXV23Uk89MFFPO9FB////ktTiksy8dIUQ1@AQMJ0aXOLp564AE0eWB4oDAA)

### Explanation

This is a standard template for programs that work entirely in ordinal mode.  Unwrapped, the program is as follows:

```
i.' -l.uQm.lay.a-'~y+'~aS+o@

i       take input as string
.       duplicate
' -     remove spaces from copy
l.u     create all-lowercase and all-uppercase versions
Q       reverse stack, so original string is on top
m       truncate original string to length of spaces-removed string
.lay    convert everything except uppercase characters to \n
.a-'~y  convert everything except \n (i.e., convert uppercase characters) to ~
+       superimpose with lowercase string
        \n becomes the corresponding lowercase character, and ~ remains as is
'~aS    convert ~ to \n
+       superimpose with uppercase string
        lowercase in existing string stays as is because it has a higher code point
        \n becomes corresponding uppercase character
o       output
@       terminate
```

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>184</s> <s>177</s> 161 bytes

```java
s->{String r="";for(int i=0,j=i,t,u;i<s.length;){t=s[i++];if(t>32){u=s[j++];r+=(char)(t<65|t>90&t<97|t>122?t:u>64&u<91?t&~32:u>96&u<123|u<33?t|32:t);}}return r;}
```

Can definitely be golfed some more..
- 16 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire* by taking the input as `char[]` instead of `String`.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##lVJNb9pAEL3nVzxzoLYAK0BLRY2xSEK@AwkmTVXEwZgFlg@b7s6SEHD/Ol0ISD20B0Y72p03OzNvRjMOFkEunrNo3J9swmkgJR4CHq1OAB4RE4MgZGhsTcAnwaMhQjMcBaLTlZaj4USrPpIC4iEaiOBiI3PV1f63cFMpZxALU6cDd0@zY5dnKascXpH2lEVDGjnWilzZ4ZlM1@EDk6rFgrVSGhlvEZFxdwUtkyqlL2uqlk/TVCl/1a98oeDRN1UtfU6rSjnvUfp3saDtcknb@UJxrSrFokdrDZLlJIlgpEQE4SQb54P2XPWmmvae/SLmfcx0@@YH@U4XgbXvfSmJzexYkT3XLppGZmSHZuqaG2gzSUbKpvhc06wJESxNy9oN5/9xNTwpHk5wJuLXCJfxG27VbM76aC6YQHvEcB@8L3ERD49MTJrMdu7tut/e3cynm8YVDvjffo0fmX0fZds2DipVGDIpDdSfW/W7mud5hmHoKS57LIt@HH2iLBrNrRxZq77dP@zlseb7L83WBXIHOXrgAc7QwzlCXKCPOhguMcAVhrjGCDfguMUYd5jgHlM8YLbb5iZiPGKOJ/xCCwI@JNogPEPhOxZ4wSt@4A0/8f5PRslJsvkD)

```java
s->{                           // Method with char-array parameter and String return-type
  String r="";                 //  Result-String
  for(int i=0,j=i,t,u;         //  Some temp integers and indices
      i<s.length;){            //  Loop over the String
    t=s[i++];                  //   Take the next character and save it in `t` (as integer)
                               //   and raise index `i` by 1
    if(t>32){                  //   If `t` is not a space:
     u=s[j++];                 //   Take `u` and raise index `j` by 1
     r+=                       //   Append the result-String with:
      (char)                   //    Integer to char conversion of:
       (t<65|t>90&t<97|t>122?  //     If `t` is not a letter:
        t                      //      Simply use `t` as is
       :u>64&u<91?             //     Else if `u` is uppercase:
        t&~32                  //      Take `t` as uppercase
       :u>96&u<123|u<33?       //     Else if `u` is lowercase or a space:
        t|32                   //      Take `t` as lowercase
       :                       //     Else:
        t);                    //      Take `t` as is
    }
  }                            //  End of loop
  return r;                    //  Return result-String
}                              // End of method
```

Comment: Take a `char[]` instead of a String for this one, you'll save up plenty of bytes!

Comment: On the other hand, [I answered too](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/129137/16236) with another algorithm. And here, I take the opposite arguments: in = `String`, out = `char[]` :-)

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 84 bytes

```java
s->{int j=0,c;for(var k:s)if((c=k&95)>0)System.out.printf("%c",c^(s[j++]|~c/2)&32);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJdb9owFH3vrziJtC5RQ1Z12sOaAaJAvwstSddpjEnGSSAJsVnspKUd@@vMgVCqaVe2LJ3rc33uPY5JQWqxn6zm@XgWUdAZEQI3JGJ42QOEJFKhsbpl5zKa2WHOqIw4s9uciTwNsi90SrLhqIEQdaxErfESMYm4fmhRJ@SZUZAMybEwo9AwaD3Z//zJbBya7kLIILV5Lu15pgihob@jukV/GmIYHxyMfv@hH47M/Y9HprNcQYWjxKhVqaxkFTzykSqthitVlclwBGKWsoFXQAZCCiVtAwP6eaTBU6CmW1uohbs8oglOMv7IcMqfcJmn88BHvwgyeNMA1@R5gQ6f7DhlXfUCvK7rrc/AlRe9M2zxt3mF74gVYNs2tlvklAZCaOjeD7pXrWazqWmaamwxDiz4nL2XFnr9MnZlukwqbVXctlz3oT/ooLaNt80RnGCMNig68NFFgFPl1hkmOMcUF4hwiRhXSHCNGW6QogeGPjhuMccdfmGADC4EPEjcI8dXFHjAI77hCd/xrK/fWjrrozR9M/31DI43DpivBvxr/YwZ5Q3TqfKhTdQ05nKN2pK31f9qZRlZGKbp/Ies/2B6RV7ulXu5@gs)

## Credits :

- Dennis for the bit twiddling as it's a good way to shorten the answer
- Fhuvi for trimming 12 bytes.

Comment: @ceilingcat that doesn't work: `Hi! Test!` should become `Hi!tEst!`, but with your solution it becomes `Hi!Test`.

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, <s>95</s> 94 + 1 = 95 bytes

+1 byte penalty for -n

Save one byte by replace from `s/\s//g` to `s/ //g`

```
$s=$_;s/ //g;$_=lc($_);while(/(.)/gs){$p=$&;$p=uc($p)if(substr($s,$-[0],1)=~/[A-Z]/);print$p;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcm9CsIwFEDhV7niRRJojQ5OIUNFHEQQwclSitbYBmt7SRrrD/rqscv5hkPa1oswHtEgxE1ApzCXToAQpcRc1QXDnMu@MrVmgk25KB3/ICmcyKF@2MTNlTl/dp1l6CKM01kWzbn6iTSJj5ngkqxpOiT5DSGBvTfFDZa27RtYt0/Y@DvpC@we2sKh0rA9vV@wass/)

Explanation:

1. Make copy of input string.
2. Remove all spaceses and transform string to lower case.
3. Then start loop over each letter. Test letter in same position in saved string for upper case. If it upper - make current letter captitalized.
   Print letter.

Note that perl need to be run with "-n" command line switch

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! If you would like, you can add a link to Try It Online: https://tio.run/# (I would add it, but I don't know if this is Perl 5 or Perl 6)

Comment: I think that you need to count `+1` byte for the `-n` flag. Other than that, this looks good! Welcome to the site! :)

Comment: @StepHen it's Perl 5, colud you add link?
I failed to run my code there in propper way.

Comment: Happy to see a new Perl golfer! I've added the TIO link to your answer and improved the formatting.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 18 bytes

```
kXz"@GX@)tk<?Xk]&h
```

Same approach as [Riley's 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128938/36398).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PzuiSsnBPcJBsyTbxj4iO1Yt4/9/dUeFwNLM5GwFp6L88jwFt/wKBa/S3ILUFAX/stQihZCMVAWfxKpKBZf8dHUA)

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <strike>108</strike> 101 bytes

```cs
using System.Linq;s=>s.Replace(" ","").Select((c,i)=>s[i]>64&s[i]<91?char.ToUpper(c):char.ToLower(c))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVBNSwMxEL3vrxj2IAm0AUEEbbtS@0Wl2tpd6UE8xHTaBrfJmmRbq/jb12y7BREv4rsM8x5v5s0IWxfaYJFbqZYQ76zDNRtJ9doIApFya2ESfATgYR13UsBGyznccqkI3dMHsURl7udKNK0zfl6tojo6TVE4qZVlA1RopGDDnsrXaPhzik2x4iaKYAEtKGwrsmyKWcoFkhDCWhhSFmPpJ0TUJPX6o3yKzs9Oytq8OL0q7SzRD1mGhgh6WfUjvd33tPC3/AjZ8VF0imxmpEN/LhKFWzikJgsStuE@l@IFro3eKujrN7jJ1xnOYbxBA8kKYcTfd9DVS58u0W1j@I5QSht/XeTQuvLzSS9O9hVjN7wbwJH/rnv@n9t6yvn4FSbtOJ6Np12oH/Hb9M/gs/gC)

- 7 bytes saved after realizing that the `char` class has static `ToUpper()` and `ToLower()` methods.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 33 bytes

```
Ａ⁰χＦＬθ¿⁼§θι Ａ⁺¹χχ¿№α§θ⁻ιχ↥§θι↧§θι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/37PQkeFwNLM5GwFp6L88jwFt/wKBa/S3ILUFAX/stQihZCMVAWfxKpKBZf89HM7QOofNW443/5@z7L3e9ac23Fo/6PGPYeWn9txbqcCWG7XoZ3n28@3A8Vbpp3bCJJ51Lj7HFDsUdtSiLpHbcshjP//AQ)

As I still don't know how to pass a string with whitespaces as a single input parameter into Charcoal code, I just assign in the header the test string to the Charcoal variable that represents what would be the first input (`θ`):

```
ＡA Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Dogθ
```

So the code has the same number of bytes as if the string were passed as first input.

You can see [here the verbose version](https://tio.run/##bY3BisIwFEX3fsXFjS8QQddd1VFBqcwI4weENLbBmrRJY3V@PraiyIBve885T5bCSSuqmHqvC0PjFPug5QkLZzuDtb1iG861yvF9UQ6/pUIm/m5Y2mLM0bDkJc64ZMnoaB0oU6ZoS2oYGwH6CFo1QVSe0nZjcnWlhmvGJ5g8duAZSPOc5n2EYwgNw6B@2WBaEvzt7rQJnnRP9ocHCPw43WOHulZOCq/@vWLP3IvKbPeZijFOL3Hqqzs) of the code.

Comment: I said in another answer but just in case you forget, just input as a python array with one element

Comment: I just require the input to have a trailing newline.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 181 bytes

I try get the minor numbers of bytes,this is my code:

```
<?php
$s=readline();
preg_match_all('/[A-Z]/',$s,$m,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$s=strtolower(str_replace(' ','',$s));
while($d=each($m[0]))$s[$d[1][1]]=strtoupper($s[$d[1][1]]);
echo $s;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzLasMwFET3@Yq7EEgGh6TrNBQ3sQOlkEfdTY0RQr5EJnJ0kew67c@7KtkEZjEMcw4ZmqbnFzI0Y2HtUTW2vaJIVjPyeJad6rWRylrBF1U2/6oXPGUhZV16OOU7uS@Kj7yUm@xQfp7yCEVH6H3vrBvRi1ilR7JKo@DAU/4PJ/E2mtaiYM0alTaCddWyThIWKtZUT3VMfbcMRNHyuEcWtXHAwmqaMjgOrb7Aq3fjFQp3g7ehI2xg/40eSoPwrn5/YOvOfw)

Comment: Instead of a Constant `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` you can use the value `256` , `$argn` is a shorter variable as `readline()` for an input and I think `ctype_upper` and use of `lcfirst` and `ucfirst` will save lots of bytes with one loop and use of `$$i` and ternary operator

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp, 104 bytes

```
(defun f(s)(map'string(lambda(x y)(if(upper-case-p x)(char-upcase y)(char-downcase y)))s(remove #\  s)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxBCsIwFESvMtSFP4seQhEXIojg0k1MftqgaT9JU1svX1NxOY95z7x8kmUhyy53cJQUBS3bNETfNfTS4WE1TZgVeUdZhGNtdOJaMCkyrY51lhWsj9@0/bv7A6USRQ79yNjcgVTAQlLCA8ih2uGavXliH4uCYz/hlIOwxWXkiFvLOOvPjEPfVEX8Ag)

Unusually short for the wordy Common Lisp!

Straightforward code:

```
(defun f (s)                     ; receive the string as parameter
  (map 'string                   ; map the following function of two arguments
       (lambda (x y)             ; x from the original string, y from the string with removed spaces
         (if (upper-case-p x)    ; if x is uppercase
             (char-upcase y)     ; get y uppercase
             (char-downcase y))) ; else get y lowercase
       s
       (remove #\  s)))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Google Sheets, 213 bytes

```
=ArrayFormula(JOIN("",IF(REGEXMATCH(MID(A1,ROW(OFFSET(A1,0,0,LEN(A1))),1),"[A-Z]"),MID(UPPER(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")),ROW(OFFSET(A1,0,0,LEN(A1))),1),MID(LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")),ROW(OFFSET(A1,0,0,LEN(A1))),1))))
```

Input is in cell `A1` and the formula breaks down like this:

- `ArrayFormula()` lets us evaluate each term of `ROW()` independently
- `JOIN()` concatenates all those independent results into a single string
- `IF(REGEXMATCH(),UPPER(),LOWER()` is what makes it alternate using upper or lower case depending on what the case was at that position in the input
- `ROW(OFFSET())` returns an array of values `1` to `A1.length` that can be fed into the `MID()` function so we can evaluate each character in turn

Results of test cases: (It's easier to read if you click though to the larger version.)

[image: TestCases]

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 80 bytes

```ruby
->a{n=a.downcase.delete' '
n.size.times{|i|(?A..?Z)===a[i]&&n[i]=n[i].upcase}
n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzLDoIwFET3fMVdUV3YP6gE4yMaozGwkrCocIONUghtVV7fXsGExM1MciZnKnOrrYPMLpa8lYzTtHjLhCukKT5RIwHiSKpEg1SLHFXbiW7m@ZR61zljjEcidl05JBuDmnJ0e0f2tjRaAUbEh4sRyQNW1fAM2@IDB5OXmML5hRWEd4Qjb2pYFxmJnUnSqLSQGYSbIPw1Bnp/2sHE//eBk9h@AQ)

Comment: You can save a couple bytes by using `n.gsub(/./){}` instead of `n.size.times{};n`: `n.gsub(/./){(?A..?Z)===a[i]?$&.upcase: $&}`.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 92 bytes

```
$p[$i++]=$-[0]while s/[A-Z]/lc($&)/e;s/\s//g;for$c(@p){substr($_,$c,1)=~tr[a-z][A-Z]};print;
```

**Explanation:**

```
$p[$i++]=$-[0]while s/[A-Z]/lc($&)/e;   #get locations of caps into an array at the same time converting letters to lowercase

s/\s//g;   #delete all spaces

for$c(@p){substr($_,$c,1)=~tr[a-z][A-Z]};   #convert lowercase letters to uppercase where uppercase letters were present

print;   # print (of course) :)
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! :)

Comment: You need to add `-n` flag to make your answer valid. A few golfing things: `s/ //g` is enough (no need `\s`), `y/a-z/A-Z/` is the same as `tr[a-z][A-Z]`, you can use `-p` flag so you don't need the last `print`, you don't need the parenthesis in `lc$&`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 40 bytes

37 bytes of code + `-F` flag. (note that on old versions of Perl, you might need to add `-an` flags)

```perl
print$F[$i++]=~/[A-Z]/?uc:lc for/\S/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9r6xYAKQVdN3@FxRl5pWouEWrZGprx9rW6Uc76kbF6tuXJlvlJCuk5RfpxwTrp///76gQWJqZnK3gVJRfnqfgll@h4FWaW5CaouBfllqkEJKRquCTWFWp4JKfDgA)

Explanations:
Thanks to `-F`, `@F` contains a list of every characters of the input.
`for/\S/g` iterates over every non-space character of the input. We use `$i` to count at which iteration we are. If `$F[$i++]` is an uppercase character (`/[A-Z]/`), then we print the uppercase current character (`uc`), otherwise, we print it lowercase (`lc`). Note that `uc` and `lc` return their argument unchanged if it isn't a letter.

---

Previous version (less golfed: 47 bytes):

```perl
 s/ //g;s%.%$_=$&;$F[$i++]=~/[A-Z]/?uc:lc%ge
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9r6xYAKQVdAvc/hfrK@jrp1sXq@qpqsTbqqhZq7hFq2Rqa8fa1ulHO@pGxerblyZb5SSrpqf@/@@oEFiamZyt4FSUX56n4JZfoeBVmluQmqLgX5ZapBCSkargk1hVqeCSnw4A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 18 bytes

```
⪫Ｅ⪫⪪θ ω⎇№α§θκ↥ι↧ιω
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYxNCsIwEEb3nmLoKoF6AldVESwVFesBhnSwoTUTx/56@RgVXHzwHjw@U6MYxjaEk1jXqZytUwf0P7j41nbqkUICiU5hjCtJHMqsNtzHHFPIur2raPpUjY7B1XsSg09SNlrB49/090KvQsjg3FvTwFp4dLDjCfL@7qmC40ACZU1Q4GuGLd8WYTm0bw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
    θ               Input string
   ⪪                Split on spaces
  ⪫   ω             Join together
 Ｅ                  Loop over each character
          §θκ       Get character from original string
        №α          Search uppercase letters
       ⎇            If true (nonzero)
             ↥ι     Uppercase the current character
               ↧ι   Else lowercase the current character
⪫                ω  Join together
                    Implicitly print
```

The recent addition of StringMap shaves off a couple of bytes:

```
⭆⪫⪪θ ω⎇№α§θκ↥ι↧ι
```

`⭆` is roughly equivalent to `⪫Ｅ`...`ω`.

Answer (score 2):

## [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 67 + 1 = 68 bytes

+1 byte for `-r` flag.

```
:A
s/$/;/
:
s/([A-Z]);(.?)/;\l\1\u\2/
t
s/(\S);/;\1/
t
s/ ;//
/ /bA
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9Za8JQFITf76/4AoUqqBf7aB4k1rjXLbEWmz643GqqJjaL249vGq1CBw5zzgwDc0K1SJKSIUL5IHUpSumSeTfyk4@snimUs1J3Nk7RiZ0nKaKL51hZPRWLfye6lEIiZ0aSNFwNW4WRJgwGsTtfUwn8g0fNP9KKtzu1oLdXAfZK0ZmeT1T9pYjSgOstsU3LvrKyoma3zl3/76e6uHGhUOA@YTyfqzDUMEdDs22Uy2VN09hOTzOVY@F7j1GObu8CYXpRWuCGvmFZ496wSv6OtPiUCjOemVNlgYmixid1ljRY0cSlxRdt1nTY8MKWLh49fPrsGPDNkACLEJuIETGv7Blz4I0jE86C6y8//i5yfS9M8sEv)

### Explanation

The algorithm is pretty simple:

1. Insert a cursor (`;`) at the end of the line:

   ```
   :A
   s/$/;/
   :
   ```
2. If the character before the cursor is an uppercase letter, lowercase it (`\l`) and uppercase the character after the cursor (`\u`), moving the cursor to the left, and branch back to `:`

   ```
   s/([A-Z]);(.?)/;\l\1\u\2/
   t
   ```
3. Otherwise, if the character before the cursor is *not* a space, move the cursor to the left and branch back to `;`:

   ```
   s/(\S);/;\1/
   t
   ```
4. Otherwise, if the cursor is preceded by a space, delete both:

   ```
   s/ ;//
   ```
5. Finally, if there are any spaces left, branch back to `:A`:

   ```
   / /bA
   ```

Answer (score 2):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 143 bytes

```rust
|s|str::to_lowercase(s).replace(' ',"").chars().zip(s.chars()).for_each(|(c,d)|print!("{}",if d.is_uppercase(){c.to_ascii_uppercase()}else{c}))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVPbTuMwEH3PV5z2ARKpBO1rVl1UINyhQNuF5QWliUMNqR1sp/d@OztOGygIMVI8zsyZM5dMVKHNW170kQoMIy5cDzt/QOfcAUnGDEYBOd0tbZSHJrC7CzPNGSIhpIkMlwJSZFMIFsdM60hNwQXMgEFmCW6JHyOmtMUVmiXoT0FBvirE20IviDUIjHzM5JipONLM1Z6vWJ5FMXO3sd2o1z0/HkRKu54/47mrqzfPT6V6ZFE8cBdu3Ei8Ra64MDW3Pl/WGzxF4nP9WOT5mtebxz4linTM@aZ5yTLN5vHS895@v/esTUJNNK0OAi6DoDS43gdiWBjqM6eziY6hzE9BINj4K6RfpClT32PGA56xEtl@cX/5frPMVmg@Y0Fw2br3VgVwQQOJkseMC@ZufZBW38gKtVsWY1tmw9xM3U1viVjXuor140wS27oQK8v3m52HJVwjqe4hzf5nYuJjkfqB73NM9aVObWxgLfNlOMlZbFgS0L1dmLWj3sBWmYH0uu3fn6hG7sr/xVxmyATlqJPnm6re57BR99JZvp3wGrpMm5pDNxPai9PCTcHjF@wrORY4khOcFcOcdrlNm40urfpFNJviUD45rdceIfuqPRapnFhYmEhCmROWRbN/CUEcQ/S0C@iGnW6pWcecXh2jsm/6yV7hjX0lZdHiuBuujOxDEdRZx/i@j@rRRflj1hD2bsPz1t7eXq1Wo5992mcNJFJs02yv2lY2oldShbJCsSpyFbiKE9KK44TC0CDWct3qdO7at4fYqWTlzyOtx1IlH2YabIR99HGAGIdIEILhCCmO8YQTDHAKjjM84xwvuECGSwxxBYE2JK6R4wavuIVCBxpdGPRQ4C9GuMMY95jgATOnFfX7B3GShCxNj58Gg1P@/Hz@kmWXQyHaMs9vXpXqaGN6xWh0N55MHmZ2XewkaPB0/Ac)

Ungolfed:

```rust
  |input: &str|
    input.to_lowercase()          // create lowercase string
         .replace(' ', "")        // remove all spaces
         .chars()                 // iterate over characters
         .zip(input.chars())      // zip with input character iterator
         .for_each(|(c, input_c)| // for each character in both strings:
           print!("{}",                  // print the following:
             if input_c.is_uppercase() { // if the input character is uppercase
               c.to_ascii_uppercase()    // `c` in uppercase
             }
             else { c }                  // else `c`
           )
         )
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 184 bytes

```go
import(."strings";u"unicode")
func f(s string)string{S:=[]rune(ReplaceAll(ToLower(s)," ",""))
for i:=range s{if i<len(S)&&u.IsUpper(rune(s[i])){S[i]=u.ToUpper(S[i])}}
return string(S)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VVPbbptAEH3oG19xjJQUJEJfK6c0cmLiOBc7Mbhpc1GFYbGJ8S6GxXaM_CV9iSr1H9pPab-mA9hKOxI6y5k5s8Pu4dv3sXj5lXj-1BszzLyIK9EsEak01XAm1R-5DA_e__5Zc5qpZjKN-DhTD3M155EvAqbqSphzH6GWoc7qNRRO07p_THPOtAFLYs9nrTjWXHEplizVMt1QoRqqqpNepIiaVupxmiErohDRh5hxzdH393Ozmw2ThBRVp-w-etT1wiGwctMVdap81TcbJWUyT_l2DJJv6vn_vHknnxMGt8zkvkQR8cQAWyXb0o1Sf0P5_ZqOQlEky2SGpoX7R7dQCvUsasAlrkEj01ra5XJjUKaFmzzypzhOxZLjVKxwns8SFqC_YCncCcOlt35GW4xJ2poPqXaU9pc8FKuy0A4E1ckzFnvrLwEVVU3L7WkuuLbjVsgc2e11sOP_zRNPnbeMLAmCsp53XLsm2StQcbXDVmmaJnZPlvs-y7IG7OHAvmgdHR01Gg06k-cRMxAI_lYa6PXLoP1e9XXsxCxP2U5bS2slF2XUe9tc0tFs47rlOLf9QRsHu6DuVUXiZdlSpMFrYnvgHo4xwgl8tBHABsMpQnQwxhkm6CLCOZ5wgSkuEeMKM_TA0YfANRLcYI4BUjjIyBESQ-T4hAVuscRnrHCHdXlT3mh04geBzcKwM55MutHT08U0jq9mnPdFktzM09TJpBzmi8XtcrW6W9fTobqT6kIIiCJvXZPHZMw11bIsOG5r4IJWam38r4YsfVabv7ZdoXh-RYaaNMmqukK_hJg2LWmSZy2LsocNMUVRNQ41dW_-wGF9RIlahTr25ANXDVQNDJCkXJPcoE76hsb6byrYvTa2UynK9r95eanxLw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Noulith](https://github.com/betaveros/noulith), 88 bytes

```perl
\s->(for(p<<-s.lower filter (!=' '))yield if(s[p[0]].is_upper)p[1].upper else p[1])join""
```

[Try it online!](https://betaveros.github.io/noulith/#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)

Answer (score 1):

## C, 103 bytes

```
i,j,c;f(char*s){for(i=j=0;c=tolower(s[j++]);)c-32&&putchar(c-32*(s[i]>64&&s[i]<91&&c>96&&c<123))&&++i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBZT8JAFIXf/RVfeaitLHELialIUOqKoLQu0fiAwwCD0GI7FZf423FqJPGBk9xl7rn3zMwV5aEQi4UqjUvCGzhi1Es2UvdrECeOqo1rm56o6XgSz2XipI/jYvHJ9VxR3tm27Vmm824nP20YUj0dVHdtO0/297ZsWxzsVY3f39recV3bLhaV971QkWbaU5Hjrn2tYTBwCqfKIpSptgquZ0RTp2CSJdngOlPihcMknkccx@@cZ9OZ7NN5kwnhSNLqfX7QjIerprWRVdGQ0A/C3ygDfdY@YVn/z5v6Kok/qlKpsLQ0E0KmqYV/0/UvGvV63bIs862PZ1miH0frukS7k2OVoB9p8/I/XDWC4K7TbVJeYvUSehzyzBGCJn18JMcMOGHIKSPOUJwz5oIXWky4ZEqbiA4xV8y45pUuCQEpIZobMm55444597zzwGd@2/fiBw)

Answer (score 1):

### **[Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.5/whatsnew/3.5.html), <s>125</s>, 124 bytes**

```
lambda s:''.join(c.upper()if i in(s.find(q)for q in s if q.isupper())else c for i,c in enumerate(s.replace(' ','').lower()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7LTsMwFAX3fMXs7EhVNt0hseBZ3m8KYucmNnVJbMdOaOHng4PYzp1zNeG7X3s3H0dz0Kh2VSvSvhDlxlsnq3IIQUdZWIMlg1RaV@ud7ArjI11GJPKxK236VwvdJE3FJNhZNSnaDa2Oqtd5H3VoVKWlQMyEKMrGb/9WxV6I1vXSSOvC0E9kHA9RHLHiOP87oeYUzRmGBR@cs@YiV12y4YpPrmm4oeUWxx2eewIPOfGRyFOufKbnhYElX7yy5Y0d7/z8Ag)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <s>106</s> 105 bytes

```
s=input()
print''.join(map(lambda(c,u):[c.lower,c.upper][u](),zip(s.replace(' ',''),map(str.isupper,s))))
```

Edit: save one byte via `print ''.join` => `print''.join`.

## Lambda form, 99 bytes

```
lambda s:''.join(map(lambda(c,u):[c.lower,c.upper][u](),zip(s.replace(' ',''),map(str.isupper,s))))
```

Answer (score 1):

## SCALA, 128 chars, 128 bytes

```
var l=s.toLowerCase().filter(x=>x!=32)
for(i<-0 to l.size-1){if(s(i).isUpper)l=l.substring(0,i)+l(i).toUpper+l.substring(i+1)}
l
```

Thanks for this challenge. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZLdbtpAEIWv66c45qZeGaykvUvqIgLOL4EEm6aqerPYa7Jh8breNTggnp06CEQqLDVR1ZFWI82nOXNGOyqkgq7l6ImFGreUJ2CFZkmk0ErTpfEhYjEmjKVtmnJNhbLUia8znozJNrvL9YxmEK5ytOzKOcvaVDGLODEXmmVW4X4tTPfzJ2LEMrP4l8YRtIRwFF@wxjFZ8thSFicOV8M0ZRkRbsnykdqIW0d1TmzxwrXccPs15fYxWRlivTKMtCxokVi1S24iYEqbP5Oa/YfzPaoRu1Zicrpva@E@5@EEZ5mcJziXBa7zacoi9GcsQ/DI0KWLZ3Tk@FD37b0Vg3VpqNwFgecHm8x8fdW7wK7@mpf1w@nvFKiwsCWO42D3VB6GTCkT3nDg3bSazaZpmpjS5xGrI5LJR11Hr/8Sh4b@Sa7CnpeUd4Rt3LV8/6E/6KCxi0MDf2mo/H2KM4zQRogOInhgOEeMC4xxiUdcgeMaT7jBBF0I3GKKHhL0IXGHFPf4hQEy@FAIoDFEjm@Y4QFzfEeBH1hUnc1/H7pf1VitfwM)

Answer (score 1):

## q/kdb+, 49 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{@[a;(&)#:[a:lower x except" "]#x in .Q.A;upper]}
```

**Examples:**

```
q){@[a;(&)#:[a:lower x except" "]#x in .Q.A;upper]}"Hi! Test!"
"Hi!tEst!"

q){@[a;(&)#:[a:lower x except" "]#x in .Q.A;upper]}"A Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Dog"
"AqUickbrOwnfoxJumpEdovertHelazYdog"

q){@[a;(&)#:[a:lower x except" "]#x in .Q.A;upper]}"testing TESTing TeStING testing testing TESTING"
"testingtESTIngteStInGTEstingtestingtestiNG"

q){@[a;(&)#:[a:lower x except" "]#x in .Q.A;upper]}"TESTING... ... ... success! EUREKA???!!! maybe, don't, NOOOOO"
"TESTING.........success!eureKA???!!!maybe,don't,nooooo"

q){@[a;(&)#:[a:lower x except" "]#x in .Q.A;upper]}"Enter        PASSWORD ---------"
"Enterpassword---------"

q){@[a;(&)(#:[a:lower x except" "]#x)in .Q.A;upper]}"A a B b C c D d E e F f G g H h I i J j K k L l M m N n O o P p Q q R r S s T t U u V v W w X x Z z"
"AabbCcddEeffGghhIijjKkllMmnnOoppQqrrSsttUuvvWwxxZz"

q){@[a;(&)#:[a:lower x except" "]#x in .Q.A;upper]}"  TEST"
"teST"
```

**Explanation:**

Find indices where input is uppercase and then apply function `upper` to those indices on a lowercase, space-removed version of the input string. Note that we cannot apply the function beyond the length of the string, so use take (`#`) to truncate the input string to length of the lowercase, space-removed version.

```
{@[a;where count[a:lower x except " "]#x in .Q.A;upper]} / ungolfed
{                                                      } / lambda function
 @[ ;                                           ;     ]  / apply FUNC to VAR at INDICES: @[VAR;INDICES;FUNC]
                                                 upper   / uppercase, upper["abc"] -> "ABC"
                                       x in .Q.A         / boolean list where input is in uppercase alphabet ABC..XYZ
                                      #                  / take this many elements from list on the right (ie truncate)
           count[                    ]                   / returns length of the stuff inside the brackets, count["ABC"] -> 3                                        
                         x except " "                    / remove " " from string
                   lower                                 / lowercase, lower["ABC"] -> "abc"
                 a:                                      / save in variable a
     where                                               / returns indices where true where[101b] -> 0 2
   a                                                     / our lowercased, space-stripped input
```

**Bonus:**

After reading the answers, thought I'd try a solution where I iterate over the input, so far I've only managed a 53 byte solution:

```
{a{$[y in .Q.A;upper x;x]}'#:[a:lower x except" "]#x}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Swift 3.0, 199 bytes

```
var s="AS Ff",i=[String](),p=[Int](),j=0;for c in s.characters{if c>="A"&&c<="Z"{p.append(j)};if c != " "{i.append(String(c).lowercased())};j=j+1};for c in p{i[c]=i[c].uppercased()};print(i.joined())
```

[Try it Online!](http://iswift.org/playground)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 110 bytes

```
$q=strtr($s=$argn,[' '=>'']);foreach(str_split($s)as$k=>$v)echo$v<lcfirst($v)?ucfirst($q[$k]):lcfirst($q[$k]);
```

### Breakdown

```
$q=strtr($s=$argn,[' '=>''])
```

We take our input (`$argn`) and store it in a smaller variable because we need it later, before stripping out all the spaces with `strtr`

```
foreach(str_split($s)as$k=>$v)
```

We then take our original string, split it into an array of characters, and loop through each of them.

```
echo$v<lcfirst($v)?ucfirst($q[$k]):lcfirst($q[$k])
```

We check to see if the current letter is uppercase (`A` is less than `a` probably because ASCII), and echo out the corresponding letter from the space-stripped string with the appropriate case.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
ŒlðḲFŒuT}¦n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUUAuv9qZWxsef//xZJsw7DhuLJGxZJ1VH3Cpm7///9BIFF1aWNrIEJyb3duIEZveCBKdW1wZWQgT3ZlciBUaGUgTGF6eSBEb2c)

Just a restructuring of [Dennis' original solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128943/85334) to avoid repeating `Œl`.

```
Œl             Lowercase the input.
  ð            Make that the left argument to the following dyadic chain.
   Ḳ           Split on spaces,
    F          flatten out the splits,
     Œu        then uppercase that
       T}¦     at the indices where
Œlð       n    the lowercase doesn't equal the original.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2), 4 bytes

```
ȧ⇩$•
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyIiLCIiLCLIp+KHqSTigKIiLCIiLCJIaSEgVGVzdCEiXQ==)

Helps to have a "with capitalisation of" built-in

### Explained

```
ȧ⇩$•­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‏​⁢⁠⁡‌­
ȧ     # ‎⁡Remove whitespace from the input
 ⇩    # ‎⁢and lowercase it
  $•  # ‎⁣Transfer the capitalisation of the original input to the stripped input.
# ‎⁤The reason for `•` doing this is because on lists, `•` is mould. Therefore, the idea was that it "moulds" one string to the capitalization of the other
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).